# Win32 window not showing when ran through CLI/VSCode debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, winapi, command-line-interface, vscode-debugger

I am creating a Win32 application, I have followed some setup code for creating a Win32 window without the need for a WinMain which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/caiorss/e8967d4d3dad522c82aab18ccd8f8304). The code builds just fine and if I run the application by opening it in a file browser it runs no problem. However, if I run it via the command line it only outputs the console logs and doesn't create a window. I assume that this is also why if I run it via VSCode's debugger it also doesn't launch a window. Has anyone come across this issue before and found a fix for it? It would be pretty had to debug a GUI application if you can't use the debugger and see it at the same time.

Comment: Maybe your compile failed because your code does not have a `WinMain()`. VSCode should give you some information in the Terminal or the Output.

Comment: @drescherjm How would the compile have failed if the code compiles successfully and runs as it should when launched via file explorer? Am I missing part of the API that allows a GUI window to be launched from the command line? Maybe. But that would not be a failed compilation

Comment: Depending on what settings you did in VSCode it may try to build before debugging.

Comment: Yes, I have VSCode setup to build my application before debugging it. At which point it calls CMake, builds the application, returns that it was built successfully then launches the debugger. If the compilation failed it would never call the debugger

Comment: I propose that tracing the value of `nCmdShow` to `std::cerr` or `std::cout` may reveal a relevant difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code contains a mistake:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
GetStartupInfo(&si);  
int nCmdShow = si.wShowWindow;
```

You forgot to check `si.dwFlags`, as indicated in [the documentation for `wShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa#members):

> If `dwFlags` specifies `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`, this member can be any of the values that can be specified in the `nCmdShow` parameter for the `ShowWindow` function, except for `SW_SHOWDEFAULT`. *Otherwise, this member is ignored.*

Comment: Thank you that was the issue, swapping nCmdShow to just use SW_SHOW made it works. Thanks